# UINavigation / inputAccessoryView issue on pushViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have 3 View Controllers .

The Top Controller is a TabViewController .

in 1st view controller i do:

```
self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

svc is my second view controller.
also i pass it the navigationController ,
and in the second vc i use

```
self.nav?.pushViewController(cvc, animated: true)
self.dismissViewController
```

now after that the view is dismissed and shows me the third vc (cvc)
but this function don't get executed

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView! {

    get {
        print("inputAccessoryView")
        if toolBar == nil {
            toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, toolBarMinHeight-0.5))

            textView = InputTextView(frame: CGRectZero)
            textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 250/255, alpha: 1)
            textView.delegate = self
            textView.text = "New Message"
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(messageFontSize)
            textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 200/255, blue: 205/255, alpha:1).CGColor
            textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            //textView.placeholder = "Message"
            textView.scrollsToTop = false
            textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 3, 3, 3)
            toolBar.addSubview(textView)

            sendButton = UIButton(type: .System)
            sendButton.enabled = false
            sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
            sendButton.setTitle("Send", forState: .Normal)
            sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 142/255, blue: 147/255, alpha: 1), forState: .Disabled)
            sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1), forState: .Normal)
            sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 6)
            sendButton.addTarget(self, action: "sendAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            toolBar.addSubview(sendButton)

            // Auto Layout allows `sendButton` to change width, e.g., for localization.
            textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
            toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 7.5))
            toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: sendButton, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: -2))
            toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8))
            toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -4.5))
        }
        return toolBar
    }
}
```

Edit:i have this func as well and still

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

can some body explain me why and how to fix that??

Answer (score 0):

Override `canBecomeFirstResponder` and return `YES`.